# @ExceptionHandler not being triggered?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

I have seen other duplicate stack overflow issues on this topic but none seem to replicate my situation.

When throwing an exception, my ExceptionHandler class is not picking it up and returning json, instead the default 500 code with the exception details is returned as HTML to the client. I have checked and Spring does initialise my ExceptionHandler class but for whatever reason the methods aren't called.

GlobalExceptionHandler.class:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RequestMapping(produces = "application/json")
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);

public GlobalExceptionHandler(){
    LOG.debug("This gets called in logs...");
}

@ExceptionHandler({CustomException.class})
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Object> handleCustomException(HttpServletRequest request,
                                             CustomException ex) {

    LOG.debug("This does not get called...");
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();

    response.put("message", ex.getMessage());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, ex.getCode());
}
}
```

CustomException.class:

```
public class CustomException extends RuntimeException{

private HttpStatus code;
private String message;

public CustomException(final HttpStatus code, final String message){

    this.code = code;
    this.message = message;
}


/**
 * Gets message.
 *
 * @return Value of message.
 */
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

/**
 * Sets new code.
 *
 * @param code
 *         New value of code.
 */
public void setCode(HttpStatus code) {
    this.code = code;
}

/**
 * Sets new message.
 *
 * @param message
 *         New value of message.
 */
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

/**
 * Gets code.
 *
 * @return Value of code.
 */
public HttpStatus getCode() {
    return code;
}
}
```

The exception handler is triggered here:

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Autowired
private JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationFilter.class);

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain
        filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

    logger.debug("Filtering request for JWT header verification");

    String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);

    logger.debug("JWT Value: {}", jwt);

    if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
        String username = tokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(jwt);

        UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                (userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    } else {

        logger.error("{}", new CustomException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "No Valid JWT Token Provided"));
        throw new CustomException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "No Valid JWT Token Provided");
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
}
```

I have all necessary properties in web config:

```
<!--<context:annotation-config />-->
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.controller"/>
```

My Web.xml:

```
<web-app>

<!-- For web context -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Logging -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>logbackConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>jwtFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.app.controller.security.filters.JwtAuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jwtFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>appDispatcher</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Been going over this issue for a while..

This is all I get:

[image]

Comment: `@RequestMapping(produces = "application/json")` should not be used in advices. And where is the exception throwed?

Comment: Ahh I'll give that a try..

Comment: No luck... Even with <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/> configured...

Comment: Where do you throw this exception?

Comment: NiVer I included that in the description... Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exception is not getting catched by the `@ControllerAdvice` because you are throwing it from a class annotated with `@Component` and not `@Controller`.

As per the documentation:

> Specialization of @Component for classes that declare
>   @ExceptionHandler, @InitBinder, or @ModelAttribute methods to be
>   shared across multiple @Controller classes.

You can find a more complete reference [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html).

Comment: Thanks. What method then would be ideal for calling the exception handler from different layers (not the controller)?

Comment: Still no luck even if I annotate the filter class with @Controller

Comment: Another problem is that filters are executed before actual interaction with your controller, that is why you don't see it. You should think of different way to handle the exception for filters.

Comment: I have checked if I throw the exception straight away in the controller that I'm sending the rest request to, it still returns as HTML and doesn't trigger the ExceptionHandler

Comment: Okay I understand now... Filter was still being called. Would you be able to fix the complete reference link you posted for more information. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Fixed. Sorry for that.